# need help on wordpress feeds query parameters

Tags: wordpress

may i know how do i set the number of feeds displayed on a word press blog?

for instance, i used

> http://beautifulreminisciencezz.wordpress.com/?feed=atom&year=2009

But it returns me only ten results.

For blogger, I know the query parameter is 'max-results'

However,t here's nowhere in wordpress where they mentioned the query parameters for this.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set it from the [Reading Settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel) in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting with WordPress myself, but I did notice the `paged=<num>` query parameter to get that `num`'th page of results.  Looks like combining this with `order=ASC&orderby=date` should allow full in-order `import` (over several pages) if you're doing this programmatically.